# Axios won't send the body parameter

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, postman

When i print the body paremeter on the back side they are undefined. But when i send the same request using POSTMAN it works. I don't know what i'm missing.

```
export const test = obj => {
  const body = qs.stringify({
    mode: obj.mode,
    partition: obj.partition
  });

  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
  };

  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: "GET_CONSIGNE_BEGIN" });
    return axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080/Mode-Partition-Consignes", body, config)
      .then(result => {
        dispatch({ type: "GET_CONSIGNE_SUCCESS", payload: result.data });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch({ type: "GET_CONSIGNE_FAILURE", err });
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: A get request doesn't generally have a body, that's not the second argument to the get method.

Comment: Because you're actually adding the body in postman? Read the docs for Axios, the second argument to get is **not** data, like post, it's config.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What? A get method does has a body. How else you would get data depending on certain variables like `_id` ? Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @AtinSingh query and path parameters, usually; the payload has no defined semantics per https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.1

Comment: On postman, i'm adding a body and it's works. My server respond correctly

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hmmm i see what you mean. Thanks for clarifying. :)

Comment: @SJS yes, and in Axios you're **not adding a body**. But also, this suggests you should change your API.

Comment: A GET request sends parameters as part of the URL in the queryString as in `http://localhost:8080/Mode-Partition-Consignes?mode=someMode&partition=somePartition`, not in the body.  If you want to send a body (that's what the server is really expecting or there's some need to), then that would happen in a POST request (but the server needs to be expecting a POST, not a GET).

Answer (score 0):

With axios, the only way to send data through GET is by the attribute params.

Example on client:

```
axios.get("/api", {
  params: {
    foo: "bar"
  }
});
```

Example on server:

```
router.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  const { foo } = req.query;
});
```

Hope it helps. Happy coding.